# How to get previosly page using https

Tags: asp.net, https

I have a problem. Before we start using https I get previously Page using this code:

```
Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

It get http header

```
Referer:http://localhost/test
```

But when we start using https they are null. 
Page.PreviouslyPage is null too.

How I can get previously page, when https is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP Referer might not be sent by the browser in this case and the only way to achieve this is to include this url as part of the request. For example you could use a hidden field or you could pass it as a query string parameter when generating the link.